# What does Scala's "try" mean without either a catch or finally block?

Tags: scala

Unlike Java, Scala lets you do a bare "try", without either a catch or finally clause:

```
scala> try { println("Foo") }
Foo
```

Does this actually have any meaning beyond,

```
{ println("Foo") }
```

?

Comment: As of Scala 2.11, we get a warning. `warning: A try without a catch or finally is equivalent to putting its body in a block; no exceptions are handled.`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Scala's exception handling works by passing any exceptions to an anonymous catch function. The catch function works by pattern matching the caught exception and, if it doesn't match it will pass the exception up.

The catch function is optional, if it's omitted then the exception is passed straight up. So essentially

```
try { exceptionThrowingFunction() }
```

is the same as

```
exceptionThrowingFunction()
```

See chapter 6.22 of the [language spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) pdf for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. I think Scala permits a try without a catch or finally because there's no reason to forbid it.

Comment: Well, presuming that there's never any actual reason to use a bare "try", a reason to forbid it would be to catch programmer mistakes and reduce potential confusion. But certainly, it's not a big deal either way.