# Apache Spark - How Exception Handling works in map function

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying url decoding on input data. Few records are decoded fine, but when i tried this on larger data it is giving error. I tried exception handling to discard error data, but getting same error again and again.

```
val decodedVal = convertedVal22.map(s => doWork(s))

def doWork(param : String) : String = 
{

   var x9 = ""
   try {
     var y = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(param, "UTF-8")
     x9 = y
    }

    return x9
}
```

Error:

```
URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "%2"
```

Comment: Where is your `catch` block? This shouldn't compile.

Comment: It is compiling without catch block, i don't think catch is mandatory.

Comment: You [learn something very day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547465/what-does-scalas-try-mean-without-either-a-catch-or-finally-block). You're not catching any exceptions if there's no `catch` block.

Comment: errrrrr you are right. one more thing i don't need anything if error occurs. So i used catch { return "" } , but is giving error 'error: value isDefinedAt is not a member of Nothing'

Answer (score 0):

Run Time exception is required to in catch block.

```
def doWork(param : String) : String = {
var x9 = ""
try {
    var y = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(param, "UTF-8")
    x9 = y
    return x9
}
catch {   

            case runtime: RuntimeException => 
            {
                ""
            }
}
```

and that filter it with nonEmpty.

```
 val decodedVal = convertedVal22.map(s => doWork(s)).filter(_.nonEmpty)
```